# How to change a button on angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using the following directive to show 3 tabs in bottom but I want to know if there is any chance to change "exterior" with "interior" as if I am on exterior page to show only "interior" and "gallery" and when i am on interior page to how "exterior" and "gallery" this is how my HTML code look like

```
<section>
    <nav >
        <ul class="nav footer-tabs">
            <li class="exterior col-sm-4"><a href="#/exterior"><img src="img/colour-options.png"></a></li>
            <li class="interior col-sm-4"><a href="#/interior"><img src="img/Interior-360.png"></a></li>
            <li class="gallery col-sm-4"><a href="#/gallery"><img src="img/View-Gallery.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: use ng-show or ng-hide in your li, and embed the logic for show/hide in your controllers.

Comment: or add a directive to li element to avoid logic in controller. the directive read the location path and through the parameter you defined in attribute you can set it visible or not... Like `<li class="exterior col-sm-4" show-on="interior, other"><a href="#/exterior"><img src="img/colour-options.png"></a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a $rootScope variable if you are dealing with multiple pages
2. Keep track whether the user is interior or exterior using the bool
3. Use ng-if/ng-show and ng-hide to show and hide the tabs

when user is in exterior page , set

```
$rootScope.isInterior = false;
```

when user is in interior page , set

```
$rootScope.isInterior = true;

<section>
    <nav >
        <ul class="nav footer-tabs">
            <li ng-show="isInterior" class="exterior col-sm-4"><a href="#/exterior"><img src="img/colour-options.png"></a></li>
            <li ng-show="!isInterior" class="interior col-sm-4"><a href="#/interior"><img src="img/Interior-360.png"></a></li>
            <li class="gallery col-sm-4"><a href="#/gallery"><img src="img/View-Gallery.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.showTab = '';
}]);


<section>
    <nav >
        <ul class="nav footer-tabs">
            <li ng-hide="showTab == 0" ng-click="showTab = 0" class="exterior col-sm-4"><a href="#/exterior"><img src="img/colour-options.png"></a></li>
            <li ng-hide="showTab == 1" ng-click="showTab = 1" class="interior col-sm-4"><a href="#/interior"><img src="img/Interior-360.png"></a></li>
            <li ng-hide="showTab == 2" ng-click="showTab = 2" class="gallery col-sm-4"><a href="#/gallery"><img src="img/View-Gallery.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Basically, click on exterior, showTab becomes 0 and you hide exterior, if you click on interior div, showTab becomes 1, exterior tab is not hidden and interior becomes hidden etc.